If the airplane tap doesn’t say “not drinking water”, is it safe to drink?
I recently flew on a Delta A220 and noticed that the bathroom didn’t have a warning about not drinking the water. Does it mean it’s safe to drink or brush your teeth with? This was the only sign above the tap:


Good hand washing takes 20 seconds. Or the time it takes to sing Happy Birthday twice. Use water to rinse your hands before and after 20 seconds of vigorous scrubbing.

Related question with a photo of a sign that does warn it’s not drinking water:  What makes the tap water on board airplanes unsafe to drink?

How fussy are you about water? Would you drink tap water everywhere without knowing what the pipes are made of or whether it is mixed with water from a container on the roof?

I never understood seeing "do not drink" in the airplane bathroom next to the little paper cups

@Willeke in developed nations I’m happy to drink from the tap, otherwise I always boil the water before drinking.

@Midavalo Rinsing your mouth after brushing your teeth (and spitting the water after that) and actually drinking the water can be quite different things, I suppose.

Why would you? Unless the seat belt sign is on (in which case you shouldn't be in the bathroom) the cabin crew will always give you water to drink if you ask for it.

@DJClayworth I for one would happily brush my teeth and rinse with the tap water if I knew it was safe.

Back in 2016, one of the answers to this Q suggests that water in newer airplanes may indeed be safe to drink: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/64861/what-makes-the-tap-water-on-board-airplanes-unsafe-to-drink

side note: Legionnaire's disease can't be contracted by drinking water, only inhaling (e.g. choking or washing your nostrils).

@Midavalo Some airlines provide mouthwash (in a pump dispenser).

This is a test comment. Frank Dernoncourt, please let me know on meta when to delete this comment

Water that is not safe to drink has to be indicated as such, the absence of such signs indicate that it is potentially safe to drink. It does not indicate that it will be nice to drink. This answer indicates that some water on planes is safe to drink these days.
If you are not fussy about using water from taps in general, you could use the water from this plane tap to brush your teeth or even to drink.
But I would suggest not to use it as a normal source of drinking water in the plane if water is free of cost available. And I would not bet on the next plane of the same make and/or airline to have the same water tank system, so bring water with you if available.
For those people who always want to be very sure about the sources of their water, if in doubt do not use the plane tapwater, it is likely safe but you would keep worrying.

This answers seems to provides no information on water quality in planes, let alone whether the absence of a “no drinking water” sign means anything. It's just some musings on what being “fussy about using water from taps” means to you…

@Relaxed, I updated the answer.
